# Delete ListWidget item by value

Tags: c++, qt, qlistwidget

I'm using a QListWidget to store labels for running background processes:

```
 // process starts
 ui->runningProcesses->addItem("Process: "+processID);
```

This is for display only. The user doesn't select items or otherwise interact with the listbox. When the background process completes I'd like to delete the corresponding listbox item. I tried:

```
 delete ui->runningProcesses->takeItem(ui->runningProcesses->findItems("Process:"+processID,Qt::MatchExactly) );
```

But it's invalid syntax. What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`QListWidget::findItems`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidget.html#findItems) returns a `QList<QListWidgetItem*>`. You can't delete the list, you need to iterate through the list and delete each item in it.

Please note that there is no need to use `QListWidget::takeItem` unless you are willing to do another thing with the returned `QListWidgetItem`.

If your aim is to just remove the item's row from the list, you just need to `delete` it. As explained in the [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidget.html#removeItemWidget):

```
auto itemsToRemove= listWidget.findItems("Process: 7", Qt::MatchExactly);
for(auto item : itemsToRemove) delete item;
```